# CNTK and outputting image data to TensorBoard

Tags: tensorboard, cntk

Is there way to output GAN generator progress as images to Tensorboard when training with CNTK? I'd like to see what images Geneartor creates as the training progresses.

I'm using this example as a starting point for training: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/v2.0.rc2/Tutorials/CNTK_206B_DCGAN.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

CNTK allows visualization of different metrics / loss with TensorBoard. More information can be found here.

https://cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.logging.progress_print.html#cntk.logging.progress_print.TensorBoardProgressWriter

Comment: Are only scalar metrics supported? Or is there way to make data flow to "Image" tab of Tensorboard? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is additional documentation on using Tensorboard with CNTK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/using-tensorboard-for-visualization